# Index out of Bound While Reading Data from Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

As You will see in code I am getting database data into `ArrayList` and passing it into `listview` , Getting Exception at `dataIntArrayList3.get(i)`. Actually there are two database, I am passing data of one database into `listview` adapter at time of fetching and getting databse of another database by using store it into array list.

```
        Cursor cursord=diffhelper.getAllData();

        if(cursord.getCount() ==0){
            return;
        }
        StringBuffer stringBuffer= new StringBuffer();
        while (cursord.moveToNext()) {

            dataIntArrayList3.add(cursord.getInt(1));
            Log.e("Difference","Dffkm:"+cursord.getInt(1));
        }

        //#######################################

        Cursor cursor=myhelper.getAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() ==0){

            return;
        }
        int i=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            customDataListModelList.add(new CustomDataListModel(cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),(cursor.getInt(1)),dataIntArrayList3.get(i)));

            Log.e("AllListData","Date:"+cursor.getString(2));
            Log.e("AllListData","Time"+cursor.getString(3));
            Log.e("AllListData","Km:"+cursor.getInt(1));

            i++;

        }
```

Logcat:

```
      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.KmListData.onCreate(KmListData.java:82)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2503)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1256)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:738)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Expected result is getting value of both database into listview. and also want to know what's wrong with my logic or code

getting result in movement of other cursor which is also posted in code:

```
 Cursor cursord=diffhelper.getAllData();

    int i=0;

    if(cursord.getCount() ==0){
        return;
    }
    StringBuffer stringBuffer= new StringBuffer();
    while (cursord.moveToNext()) {

        dataIntArrayList3.add(cursord.getInt(1));
        Log.e("Difference","Dffkm:"+cursord.getInt(1));

        Log.e("datachecking","arrayvlue:"+dataIntArrayList3.get(i));

        i++;

    }
```

Logcat of that is:

```
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:60
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:63
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:-126
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:0
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:1
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:-1
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:0
2019-02-19 13:00:29.547 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:9
2019-02-19 13:00:29.550 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:-9
2019-02-19 13:00:29.550 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:1
2019-02-19 13:00:29.550 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:-1
2019-02-19 13:00:29.551 6269-6269/com.quad14.obdnewtry E/datachecking: arrayvlue:1
```

Comment: Where is ArrayList initialization?

Comment: what is your code here: `com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.KmListData.onCreate(KmListData.java:82)`?

Comment: @Amy In onCreate of Fragment, do u like me to posting whole code of that Fragmnet

Comment: @psKink this just showing in which file and which line is cause of exception

Comment: yes i know, so what is your code there?

Comment: @pskink on             customDataListModelList.add(new CustomDataListModel(cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),(cursor.getInt(1)),dataIntArrayList3.get(i)));    like i said because of dataIntArrayList3.get(i)

Comment: take a for loop for better result and crash free !

Comment: Where you are getting the data from arraylist show us that code.

Comment: so if `dataIntArrayList3.get(0)` throws your exception it means that `dataIntArrayList3` is empty - it does not have any items

Comment: Debug the code and see whether data is available in the arraylist or not.

Comment: @pskink  sry for that earlier code actually i m getting value at 0 index . i did update comment

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you mean

Comment: @Amy & pskink I update my post see that , U can clearly see that database or array is not empty , problem is related to Reading of data at Cursor cursor=myhelper.getAllData();

Comment: why do you want to read your cursor at all? why dont you simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`? 5-7 lines of code and you are done...

Comment: @pskink thanks for inform me , I will try that now

Comment: 40 examples here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        **if (dataIntArrayList3.size() < i){
            break;
        }**
        customDataListModelList.add(new CustomDataListModel(cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),(cursor.getInt(1)),dataIntArrayList3.get(i)));

        Log.e("AllListData","Date:"+cursor.getString(2));
        Log.e("AllListData","Time"+cursor.getString(3));
        Log.e("AllListData","Km:"+cursor.getInt(1));

        i++;

    }
```

Comment: not solving problem and also by doing that i can't get data into list

Comment: then try for loop or foreach loop. First move cursor to moveToFirst() and then for loop

Answer (score 0):

Actually u must change cursor location to the first

```
Cursor cursord=diffhelper.getAllData();

int i=0;

cursord.moveToFirst();

if(cursord.getCount() ==0){
    return;
}
StringBuffer stringBuffer= new StringBuffer();
while (cursord.moveToNext()) {

    dataIntArrayList3.add(cursord.getInt(1));
    Log.e("Difference","Dffkm:"+cursord.getInt(1));

    Log.e("datachecking","arrayvlue:"+dataIntArrayList3.get(i));

    i++;

}
```

Comment: thanks for ans but if I go by your way then I won't be able to INIT my List adaptor , I Know the Issue , the problem was in size of array (There is no value for first index for  dataIntArrayList3 )because for get difference I need least 2 records , so just manually put first entry as 0 for that and everything is fine now